# The parent bundle has the same identifier (bundle.identifier) as sub-bundle

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, xcode-build-settings

So I just recently added a POD to my project which then required me to use/load workspaces instead of the individual project. That's all fine and dandy but now the build script that we use to ultimately build the project (see below) will build successfully but upon installation, I've discovered upon examining the device console logs (some lines pasted below) while trying to install it that it fails to do so because of the parent bundle identifier is the same as the sub-bundle (I assume this is referring to this one library I added - JSONWebToken).

I suppose the question I have is how do I get around this?  We have a script that appends the appropriate bundleId (we have multiple apps we build from the same code base).  It seems to me xcodebuild will use this bundleId correctly for the main app but it is using it for the POD package as well.  How do I get around this using xcodebuild?

```
xcodebuild -workspace "CompanyOne.xcworkspace" -scheme "Arrow" -configuration "Release" archive -archivePath "~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/2021-12-01/Envoy Bag Drop 12-01-21 11.23 PM.xcarchive" -allowProvisioningUpdates PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=com.companyone.retail.demo PRODUCT_NAME="Envoy Bag Drop" GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS='USE_SKIN_INCLUDE=1 RETAIL=1 SKIN_OVERRIDE_KEY=@\"*retail\"' | tee "/tmp/_xc-archive_envoy-demo_Release/build.log" | grep --color -E 'warning:|error:'
```

```
installd        0x16b54f000 -[MIInstallableBundle performPreflightWithError:]: 433: The parent bundle has the same identifier (com.luxerone.retail.demo) as sub-bundle at /var/installd/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.DUYvYU/extracted/Payload/Arrow.app/Frameworks/JWT.framework
default 17:31:21.582751-0800    installd        0x16b54f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Preflight stage failed
default 17:31:21.582992-0800    runningboardd   Invalidating assertion 31-271-3129 (target:system) from originator [daemon<com.apple.mobile.installd>:271]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75886246/the-parent-bundle-has-the-same-identifier-io-flutter-flutter-app-as-sub-bundle This worked for me.