# The parent bundle has the same identifier (io.flutter.flutter.app) as sub-bundle

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase

I'm trying on run flutter app on iOS emulator. But the android studio console show this error:

```
Unable to install /Users/bmacapital/Desktop/Development/Studio 
Projects/research/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app on 
4929DF8A-575B-45A4-8A3A-95C7D3998A48. This is sometimes caused by 
a malformed plist file:
ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
An error was encountered processing the command 
(domain=IXUserPresentableErrorDomain, code=1):
Unable To Install “App”
Please try again later.
The parent bundle has the same identifier 
(io.flutter.flutter.app) as sub-bundle at /Users/bmacapital/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4929DF8A- 
575B-45A4-8A3A95C7D3998A48/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.stagin 
g/temp.wdgr5g/extracted/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework
Underlying error (domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain, code=57):
The parent bundle has the same identifier 
(io.flutter.flutter.app) as sub-bundle at /Users/bmacapital/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4929DF8A- 
575B-45A4-8A3A95C7D3998A48/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.stagin 
g/temp.wdgr5g/extracted/Runner.app/Frameworks/App.framework
Command: /usr/bin/arch -arm64e xcrun simctl install 4929DF8A-575B-45A4-8A3A-95C7D3998A48 
/Users/bmacapital/Desktop/Development/Studio 
Projects/research/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app
Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro Max.
```

I run command `flutter create -i swift .` to generate my runner folder.

Now I want to run this app on iOS emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Flutter Project in Xcode,
Follow this hierarchy

Runner => Build Settings => Packaging => Info.plist file

make sure this info. plist file = Runner/Info.plist

thanks